# Facebook like button correct thumbnails not working properly in wordpress post listing page

Tags: wordpress, facebook, post, facebook-like, thumbnails

I am using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-to-any/ this plugin to show facebook like button on post listing page in wordpress. In my post listing I am showing thumbnail of the posts as well. I want when someone like a post then it should be posted in his/her facebook wall. Which is happening properly but the thumbnaiul image on fb wall is not showing properly.

When I am liking 2nd post then it is posting image of some other posts on that page randomly. I want to show the image of that particular posts on fb wall which is liked by user. I think this is happening because I have multiple images on the same page and facebook is not able to decide which image to choose, so it picks a random image form the page. Whereas on the post details page, there is only oine image in that case it is working fine and showing correct image on fb wall.

Is there any way to fix this in wordpress listing pages?